# formula based on data from other formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking for help with a formula

In cells `A32:A37` I have a list of events.
In cells `D32:D37` I have the date of those events

In cell `I23` I have used the following index formula to work out the date of the closest event

```
=INDEX(D32:D37,MATCH(MIN(F32:F37),F32:F37,1))
```

But now I want cell `H23` to automatically populate the name of the event based on the data in `I23`

Any ideas

Oh, and this is in Excel 2010, help greatly appreciated

Many thanks in advance

Dean

Comment: In H23, try `=INDEX(A32:A37,MATCH(I23,D32:D37,0)`.  Match type of 0 will work if there is an exact match to the I23 date in the column D list. If not, you'll have to use 1 or -1 and column D will need to be ordered either ascending or descending.  More about: [MATCH()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function).

Comment: @Dean I think Bandersnach had solved the Query, if NOT, what you kept in Column F, if Date then, is there relation with both Date columns? Specify or load Sample Data.

Comment: Thanks peeps, because this was needed for a user query, I ended up flipping the order of the dates and venues so date was on the left and venue on the right, then used a vlookup to get my result, however I checked  Bandersnach's solution with an unedited copy and that works too, so many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks peeps, because this was needed for a user query, I ended up flipping the order of the dates and venues so date was on the left and venue on the right, then used a vlookup to get my result, however I checked Bandersnach's solution with an unedited copy and that works too, so many thanks :)